# Compojure: Nested route issue

Tags: clojure, compojure

I'm trying to set up routes in my application such that:

- /:locale/ -> Home, with locale binding
- /:locale/search -> Search,
  with locale binding

Thus far, my routing code is:

```
(defn controller-routes [locale]
  (home/c-routes locale)
  (search/c-routes locale)))


(defroutes app-routes
  (route/resources "/")
  (context "/:locale" [locale]
    (controller-routes locale))
  no-locale-route
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))
```

search/c-routes:

```
(defn c-routes [locale]
 (GET "/search" [] (index locale)))
```

home/c-routes:

```
(defn c-routes [locale]
   (GET "/" [] (index locale)))
```

I can't understand why this doesn't work properly, but currently "/uk/search/" matches correctly, but "/uk/" gives the 404 page.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`controller-routes` is a normal function which as of now returns the last route i.e search and hence only search works. What you need is make `controller-routes` a route using `defroutes` and changing the c-routes as well:

search/c-routes:

```
(def c-routes (GET "/search" [locale] (index locale)))
```

home/c-routes:

```
(def c-routes (GET "/" [locale] (index locale)))
```

Where you use above routes:

```
(defroutes controller-routes
  home/c-routes
  search/c-routes)


(defroutes app-routes
  (route/resources "/")
  (context "/:locale" [locale]
    controller-routes)
  no-locale-route
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))
```

Comment: Works like a charm — thanks. Both of the c-routes should be defroutes, though, right?

Comment: `defroutes` is to compose multiple routes in a single handler i.e either one of the handler will succeed, the c-routes are individual handlers hence defined using `GET`, but when you compose them then you use `defroutes` as done in case of controller-routes

Comment: I see. But what if I wanted to have multiple routes in one of my c-routes? Could I just wrap them with a list?

Comment: Then you need to use defroutes